# how to store data to mysql in array multiple

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

[this is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHuH.png)

how to create an array for every row like`('algo'=>'input1','algo'=>'input2'`
then `('algo2'=>'input1','algo2'=>'input2')`
i want to do this for dynamic number of topics and also want to insert in mysql 
through php.  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLMt9.png) is how i want to store the array values

```
 $sel=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from srs");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($sel);
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) 
   {
       echo '<tr>
       <td class="col-sm-2">'.$row['name'].'</td>
      <td class="col-sm-2"><a href="#" id="add"  ><img src="../images/add.png"></a> / <a href="#" id="rem"  ><img src="../images/rem.png"></a></td>                   
              </tr>';
              $i++;
              }
```

Comment: your questions is not clear enhance your question

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
   $new_array =array(); //array initialzise
 $sel=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from srs");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sel);
  $i=0;
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) 
  {
        $new_array[]=$row["topic_name"];

   echo '<tr>
   <td class="col-sm-2">'.$row["name"].'</td>
  <td class="col-sm-2"><a href="#" id="add"  ><img src="../images/add.png"></a> / <a href="#" id="rem"  ><img src="../images/rem.png"></a></td>                   
          </tr>';
          $i++;
          }
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: sir   plz see the attached images,images will help you better understand my problem n  thanx for help :)